# How to swap map elements

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, swap

In C++, how would I swap two elements of a `map`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by swap in a map? A normal plain vanila map doesn't have any particular order so speaking of swapping has no meaning in reference to order.

If you are looking for C++ map implementation that preserves order, in which case ordering becomes meaningful then look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899564/a-c-hash-map-that-preserves-the-order-of-insertion)

If however you are looking to swap the value associated with one key with the value associated with a second key then just do

```
map<char, string> myMap;

myMap['a'] = "firstValue";
myMap['b'] = "secondValue";

/* Now let's swap */
string tmpString = myMap['a'];
myMap['a'] = myMap['b'];
myMap['b'] = tmpString
```

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that there isn't really an order associated with maps... thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: `std::map` does maintain a sorted order, this is why it is implemented as a self-balancing binary search tree. You maybe confused it with `std::unordered_map`, which is basically a hash map - without any particular order.

Answer (score 7):

The provided answers are correct but are using `operator[]` twice for the same keys, which isn't free and could be avoided :

```
std::map<char, std::string> a;
```

Solution 1 :

```
std::string &item1 = a['a'];
std::string &item2 = a['b'];
std::swap(item1, item2);
```

Solution 2 :

```
const std::map<char, std::string>::iterator item1 = a.find('a');
const std::map<char, std::string>::iterator item2 = a.find('b');
if ((item1 != a.end()) && (item2 != a.end()))
    std::swap(item1->second, item2->second);
```

Of course, the two solutions aren't equivalent (solution 2 only swaps values which are already in the map, solution 1 inserts without questioning and might end up swapping two default constructed strings).

Comment: Is solution 1 safe? I can't find anything in the STL docs to say that a reference to a value in a map won't get invalidated by an insertion, though it appears to be Ok in g++.

Comment: @Pete I think it is, 23.1.2/8 "The insert members shall not affect the validity of iterators and references to the container"

Answer (score 3):

I think `std::swap()` is a good choice.

Comment: Unfortunately `std::map<T>::iterator` is a const iterator, preventing the user from modifying the sorted order outside of the class. You have to cast away the `const`-ness with a `const_cast` first to perform an `std::swap`.

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers provided so far deal with nonexistant keys and preserving the nonexistance of these keys.

```
template<class Key, class Value>
void swap_map_elements(std::map<Key, Value>& map, const Key& key1, const Key& key2)
{
    auto it1 = map.find(key1);
    auto it2 = map.find(key2);
    auto end = map.end();

    if(it1 != end && it2 != end) {
        std::swap(it1->second, it2->second);
    }
    else if(it1 != end) {
        map.emplace(std::make_pair(key2, std::move(it1->second)));
        map.erase(key1);
    }
    else if(it2 != end) {
        map.emplace(std::make_pair(key1, std::move(it2->second)));
        map.erase(key2);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
auto M = std::map<int, std::string>();
M.emplace(std::make_pair(1, "one"));
M.emplace(std::make_pair(2, "two"));

swap_map_elements(M, 1, 2); // 1: "two", 2: "one"
swap_map_elements(M, 1, 4); // 2: "one", 4: "two"
swap_map_elements(M, 5, 2); // 4: "two", 5: "one"
swap_map_elements(M, 8, 9); // 4: "two", 5: "one"
```

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
  auto mymap = std::map<int, char>{{1, 'a'}, {2, 'b'}};
  std::swap(mymap.at(1), mymap.at(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
const T tmp = map["a"];
map["a"] = map["b"];
map["b"] = tmp;
```